# Summarise() doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: r, dplyr

This question sounds so unreasonable to me that I'm convinced I'm missing something obvious, but it can't find it. I have a `tibble`, whose first 200 rows are at the end of this question.

The code I tried was this:

```
record %>%
  group_by(samples, rep, bests) %>%
  summarise(prop = round(n()/samples, 2))
```

However, this didn't have the expected output. This is what it did:

```
> record %>%
+   group_by(samples, rep, bests) %>%
+   summarise(prop = round(n()/samples, 2))# %>%
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'samples', 'rep', 'bests' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 200 x 4
# Groups:   samples, rep, bests [41]
   samples   rep bests   prop
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1      10     1 Change   0.3
 2      10     1 Change   0.3
 3      10     1 Change   0.3
 4      10     1 Stay     0.6
 5      10     1 Stay     0.6
 6      10     1 Stay     0.6
 7      10     1 Stay     0.6
 8      10     1 Stay     0.6
 9      10     1 Stay     0.6
10      10     2 Change   0.5
# … with 190 more rows
```

And what it should have done:

```
> record %>%
+   group_by(samples, rep, bests) %>%
+   summarise(prop = round(n()/samples, 2))# %>%
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'samples', 'rep', 'bests' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   samples, rep, bests [41]
   samples   rep bests   prop
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1      10     1 Change   0.3
 2      10     1 Stay     0.6
 3      10     2 Change   0.5
 4      10     2 Stay     0.5
```

What did I do wrong? Is is `summarising()` not summarising?

My data:

```
record <- structure(list(samples = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
    rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 21), bests = c("Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", 
    "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Change", "Change", 
    "Change", "Change", "Stay", "Stay", "Change", "Stay", "Change", 
    "Stay", "Stay", "Change")), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You are dividing by the whole column `samples`.  From dplyr  >= 1.0, `summarise` returns more than one row per group

Comment: You can see in the output that there are 41 groups in the example data, so you should not expect 4 rows of summarised output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `dplyr` version `>= 1.0`, if there are more than one row per group, there is no restriction on `summarise` to return only a single row per group.  Here, in the OP's code, it is dividing by 'samples' which is the full column and that is the issue.  We can `summarise` the 'samples' as the `first` element of 'samples' (without using 'samples' as grouping variable)

```
library(dplyr)
record %>%
    group_by(rep, bests) %>%
    summarise(samples = first(samples),
               prop = round(n()/samples, 2), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 41 x 4
#     rep bests  samples  prop
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 Change      10   0.3
# 2     1 Stay        10   0.6
# 3     2 Change      10   0.5
# 4     2 Stay        10   0.5
# 5     3 Change      10   0.7
# 6     3 Stay        10   0.3
# 7     4 Change      10   0.9
# 8     4 Stay        10   0.1
# 9     5 Change      10   0.6
#10     5 Stay        10   0.4
# … with 31 more rows
```

---

Or another option is to first do the `count` which effectively summarise to unique rows and then create a proportion with `mutate`

```
record %>% 
    count(samples, rep, bests) %>%
    mutate(prop = round(n/samples, 2))
```